# Botbuilder route action message to correct dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am building a bot with the botbuilder framework using node, and I am now trying to use the CardAction.dialogAction:

```
builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, 'help', 'topic:mytopic', 'Click me')
```

It generates a message that looks like this:

```
action?help=topic:mytopic
```

Now I need to route that action to the correct dialog to handle it, but I can't figure out where and how to do that. Seeing as this is a builtin feature, I figured there should be easy ways of doing this already?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: This was the way to use it, but since v3.8 it seems to be a bug and not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For a lack of any other options at this point I resorted to writing my own simple action recognizer. It is no beauty, but it does the trick.

```
function action_recognizer() {
  return {
    recognize: function (context, done) {
      let intent = { score: 0.0 }
      const text = context.message.text
      if (text) {
        const m = text.match(/action\?(\w+)=?(.+)/)
        logger.debug(m)
        if (m) {
          switch (m[1]) {
          case 'help':
            intent = { score: 1.0, intent: 'help' }
            if (m.length > 2) {
              intent.entities = [{entity: m[2], type: 'custom_intent'}]
            }
            break
          }
        }
      }
      done(null, intent)
    }
  }
}
```

This will basically direct to my `help:/` dialog. Which in turn will read the entities list (if custom_intent types are available).